# How to execute test cases in protractor with different conditions?

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, protractor

I have written condition for executing different test cases in different scenarios, but it is always executing `else` condition only even it is true. Is there any other approach to handle test cases with different condition?

```js
describe('some', () => {
  if (value == "true") {
    it('steps-1', async() {
      //some steps
    });
  } else {
    it('steps-2', async() {
      //some steps
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that value is `"true"` (string), not `true` (boolean)?

Comment: for example i kept true..its not about value

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
describe('some', () => {
    it('steps-1', async(){
        if(value!=="true") this.skip();
        //else do some steps
    });

    it('steps-2', async(){
        if(value==="true") this.skip();
        //else do some steps
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because protractor not able to find  `value`.

You can try this

```
describe('some', () => {
  $('#abc').isPresent().then(function (value) { // $('#abc') some element on your UI

  if (value === true) {
    it('steps-1', ()=> {
      //some steps
    });
  } else {
    it('steps-2', ()=> {
      //some steps
    });
  }
});
});
```